# ErrorException in SimpleMessage.php line 474: Undefined index: 01:11 Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

estoy tratando de mandar un correo mediante mi controlador y me salta el error de

```
ErrorException in SimpleMessage.php line 474: Undefined index: 01:11
```

No entiendo el error ya que mi variable no esta vacia.. lo comprobe haciendo un `var_dump($data[desde_las]); die;` y me trae correctamente la hora 01:00,
alguna idea de porque esta fallando esto?
mi controlador

```
public function update(Request $request) {
    $permiso = Permiso::find($request->solicitud_id);
    $permiso->estado = $request->estado;
    $permiso->save();

    if ($permiso->estado == 'aprobado') {
        $data = [
            'cedula' => $permiso->cedula,
            'nombre'=> $permiso->nombre,
            'apellido' => $permiso->apellido,
            'departamento' => $permiso->departamento,
            'jefe_directo' => $permiso->jefe_directo,
            'tipo_licencia' => $permiso->tipo_licencia,
            'fecha_desde' => $permiso->fecha_desde,
            'desde_las' => $permiso->desde_las,
            'fecha_hasta' => $permiso->fecha_hasta,
            'a_las' => $permiso->a_las,
            'dia_completo' => $permiso->dia_completo,
            'cantidad_horas' => $permiso->cantidad_horas,
            'motivo' => $permiso->motivo,
            'recuperar_dia' => $permiso->recuperar_dia,
            'de_' => $permiso->de_,
            'hasta_las' => $permiso->hasta_las,
            'celular_solicitante' => $permiso->celular_solicitante,
            'correo_solicitante' => $permiso->correo_solicitante
        ];

        $emails = ['hernachaparro@gmail.com', 'hernanchaparro1@hotmail.com'];
        // envio de correo al jefe de todos los departamentos
        Mail::send('formularios.SolicitudPermiso.envioMail2', $data, function($message) use ($data, $emails) {
             $message->from('hernachaparro@gmail.com', 'Formulario Chacomer');
             $message->to($emails);
             $message->subject('Solicitud de permiso');
             $message->priority($data['cedula']);
             $message->priority($data['nombre']);
             $message->priority($data['apellido']);
             $message->priority($data['departamento']);
             $message->priority($data['jefe_directo']);
             $message->priority($data['tipo_licencia']);
             $message->priority($data['fecha_desde']);
             $message->priority(strval($data['desde_las']. ' hs'));
             $message->priority($data['fecha_hasta']);
             $message->priority($data['a_las']);
             $message->priority($data['dia_completo']);
             $message->priority($data['cantidad_horas']);
             $message->priority($data['motivo']);
             $message->priority($data['recuperar_dia']);
             $message->priority($data['de_']);
             $message->priority($data['hasta_las']);
             $message->priority($data['celular_solicitante']);
             $message->priority($data['correo_solicitante']);

        }); 

        session()->flash('notify', 'Formulario aprobado!');
        return redirect()->back();

    } else {
        session()->flash('notify', 'Formulario rechazado!');
        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

El campo desde_las es un campo de tipo text que envia la hora que el usuario ingresa, por ejemplo 02:00 o 15:00, no todas las veces falla pero cuando el usuario ingresa 01:00 o 02:00 falla siempre...

Comment: Ya intentaste suprimir el strval(). Supongo que el campo "a_las" también es texto. Podrías en la tabla de tu base de datos usar también valores tipo time y date o unificarlos en datetime para no tener dobles columnas. O si quieres mantener esa estructura en tu array haces la conversión:           'desde_las' => (string)$permiso->desde_las, o            'desde_las' => strval($permiso->desde_las),

Comment: lo del strlval se me quedo nomas ya.. no me di cuenta.. pense que conviertiendo a un string funcionaria pero luego me di cuenta que el campo es luego un string... Osea la conversion no es el problema... yo mas bien pienso que es por el metodo priority().. porque si pongo dentro de un subject() funciona.

Comment: Seguramente ahí tal vez haya un conflicto como dices, que bueno que lo solucionaste.